# Is there an R function to convert multiple columns into one column, creating another new column to give each value a name?

Tags: r

Using R, I have parasite abundance data which is 7 columns with count data. Each row has a value for spleen weight, which represents the spleen weight for that particular sample. For the purpose of analysis, I wish to create a graph with spleen weight on the x axis and the parasite abundance of each of the seven species on the y axis. I have produced this type of graph before using ggplot2, however, to do so I rearranged the values in excel first.

I wish to convert this:

```
data.frame(
    Heligmosomoides = c(0L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Heligmosoma = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 19L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Trichuris = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
    Mastophorus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Aoncotheca = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Syphacia = c(0L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 71L, 0L, 0L, 212L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 361L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 532L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Tapeworms = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L), 
    spleenweight = c(1.111, 1.119, 1.112, 1.137, 1.137, 1.14, 1.15, 1.262, 1.121, 1.196, 1.129, 1.147, 1.226, 1.22, 1.118, 1.165, 1.114, 1.354, 1.137, 1.175, 1.3811, 1.239, 1.26, 1.216, 1.141, 1.226, 1.366, 1.155, 1.221, 1.156, 1.87, 1.211, 1.4, 1.219, 1.166, 1.227, 1.153, 1.331, 1.232)
)
```

Into this:

```
data.frame(
    Spleen.weight = c(1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4, 1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4, 1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4, 1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4, 1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4, 1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4, 1.155, 1.15, 1.175, 1.118, 1.239, 1.14, 1.121, 1.87, 1.141, 1.156, 1.26, 1.119, 1.137, 1.129, 1.112, 1.111, 1.114, 1.137, 1.166, 1.137, 1.153, 1.331, 1.262, 1.22, 1.354, 1.3811, 1.226, 1.366, 1.232, 1.147, 1.211, 1.219, 1.227, 1.216, 1.165, 1.226, 1.221, 1.196, 1.4), 
    Count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 42L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 71L, 0L, 212L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 532L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 361L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Parasite = factor(c("Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Heligmosoma", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Trichuris", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Mastophorus", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Aonchotheca", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Syphacia", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms", "Tapeworms"))
)
```

After I have my converted data, I use ggplot to plot the data.

```
splab <- ggplot(DF8, aes(x=ï..Spleen.weight, y=Count), group=Parasite, color=Parasite) + 
  geom_point()
```

For some reason this ggplot code doesn't seem to use color to seperate the parasite groups.

Comment: `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather`

Comment: Make sure you put your `color=Parasite` inside the `aes()`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you MrFlick, fixed that error too.

Comment: Appreciate if the OP can share the answer to remove this question from the "unanswered question" list.